# set autoPlay false on Flowplayer in jQuery

Tags: jquery, flowplayer

I'm using jQuery and Flowplayer to turn links to FLV files into embedded videos like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if($('a[type^="video"]').length > 0) {
        $('a[type^="video"]').each(function() {
            var video_path = $(this).attr('href');
            var video_box  = $(this).parent();
            video_box.html('');
            video_box.css('width', '680px');
            video_box.css('height', '460px');
            video_box.flowplayer('/sites/default/files/flowplayer-3.2.7.swf', video_path);
        });
    }
});
```

This is working fine except that all the videos start playing simultaneously. I've tried adding `autoPlay: false` several different ways, but so far none have worked. From the documentation it seems like I should be able to do it this way:

```
video_box.flowplayer('/sites/default/files/flowplayer-3.2.7.swf', video_path, {clip: {autoPlay: false}});
```

But that doesn't work.

Comment: Please add `var` before your variable (where you 'initialize' them), or they will 'clutter' the global scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to work like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[type^="video"]').each(function(index) {
        var video_path = $(this).attr('href');
        var video_box  = $(this).parent();
        video_box.html('');
        video_box.css('width', '680px');
        video_box.css('height', '460px');
        video_box.attr('id', 'player-' + index);
        $f(video_box.attr('id'), '/sites/default/files/flowplayer-3.2.7.swf', {
            clip: {
                autoPlay: false,
                url: video_path
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The key to getting the `$f()` function to work was to give it an id. The divs I was using didn't have ids so I gave them one with the line `video_box.attr('id', 'player-' + index);`.

I still don't know why I couldn't get the jQuery object.flowplayer() method to accept the `autoPlay: false` property. But I suppose using the `$f()` function is just as good. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

@Kevin

You don't need an extra div surrounding the flowplayer-a-tag. All you need to do is set display:block on the a-tag.

So your code can be condensed to this:

```
    $('a[type^="video"]').each(function(i) {
        $(this).css({'width': '680px','height': '460px','display': 'block'}).attr('id', 'player-' + i);
        var player = $f('player-' +i, '../flowplayer.commercial-3.2.7.swf', {
            clip: {
                autoPlay: false
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the syntax, that is used in the [documentation](http://flowplayer.org/documentation/api/index.html)? In your each loop you can do:

```
$f(this.parentNode, {src: "flowplayer.swf"}, {
  clip: {
    url: video_path
    autoPlay: false,
    onStart: function(clip){alert("Clip "+ clip.url);}  // attach event listener
  },
});
```

A side note: The line `if($('a[type^="video"]').length > 0) {` is not necessary, because jQuery will only loop through the elements, if there are any, otherwise it just skips the block.

Comment: I'm not getting something. I tried your example several different ways but I can't get it to work. It seems like `this` would not work as the first parameter to `$f` because its a jquery object. Correct?

Comment: this is a dom object and should according to the documentation work

Comment: just saw a flaw in my code and updated it. Your code stated $(this).parent() which is this.parentNode in my code. If it is still not working do you have an example page or a jsFiddle?

Comment: Sorry for the late response I got pulled off this project to work on something else for a couple of days, and I am just now getting back to it. I got your way to work. I'll post the working code as a separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass flowplayer an object of options, one of which is autoplay, here is the documentation for this: http://flowplayer.org/documentation/configuration/

This is an example from the above page:

```
flowplayer("player", {
    src: "flowplayer.swf"
}, {
    clip:  {
        autoPlay: false,
        autoBuffering: true
    }
});
```

Flowplayer has tons of options you can set on initialization including event bindings for things like `onPause` and `onPlay`.