# Remove video element with media queries

Tags: javascript, html, css, video, media-queries

I have a background video that I want to remove when the screensize is smaller than 979px. The following pieces of code are inside an Joomla based website. Which uses the latest jquery.

I am using the following css:

```
/*
VIDEO/TEXT BACKGROUND STYLING
*/
/*NON RESPONSIVE ELEMENTS*/
video.backgroundvids {
z-index: -1;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
overflow: hidden;
object-fit: fill!important;
display:block;
}
/*RESPONSIVE ELEMENTS*/
@media (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 479px) {
.ls-mobileview {display:block;}
.ls-desktopview {display:none;}
video.backgroundvids {display:none;}
}
@media (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {
.ls-mobileview {display:block;}
.ls-desktopview {display:none;}
video.backgroundvids {display:none;}
}
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
.ls-mobileview {display:block;}
.ls-desktopview {display:none;}
video.backgroundvids {display:none;}
}
@media (min-width: 980px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
.popper {position: fixed;right: 10px;bottom: 10px;}
.ls-mobileview {display:none;}
.ls-desktopview {display:block;}
video.backgroundvids {display:block;}
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
.popper {position: fixed;right: 10px;bottom: 10px;}
.ls-mobileview {display:none;}
.ls-desktopview {display:block;}
video.backgroundvids {display:block;}
}
```

In combination with the following HTML and JS:

```
<div class="ls-desktopview">
 <video preload="none" autoplay loop id="backgroundvids" class="backgroundvids">
  <source src="images/clientvideos/frontpage/video.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
  <source src="images/clientvideos/frontpage/video.ogv" type="video/ogg"/>
  <source src="images/clientvideos/frontpage/video.webm" type="video/webm"/>    
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
 </video> 
<div style="display:inline-block;"><button onclick="playPause()" class="btn btn-primary btn-grey">Play/Pause</button></div> 
<div style="display:inline-block;">{modal index.php/welcome}<div class="popper"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-orange">More Information</button></div>{/modal}</div>
```

```
<div class="ls-mobileview">
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
$('video').attr('src', '');
</script>
 <div class="page-header"><h2><a href="#">Headertext!</a></h2></div>
 <p>Paragraphtext</p> 
</div>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
var myVideo=document.getElementById("backgroundvids"); 
function playPause()
{ 
if (myVideo.paused) 
  myVideo.play(); 
else 
  myVideo.pause(); 
}
</script>
```

I have tried numerous things to resolve it but it keeps loading the video element on small screen sizes. Any solution to remove the src or the entire video element(preferred) would be greatly appreciated.

My last try is the above code. When mobileview is loaded I added the code `<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">    $('video').attr('src', '');    </script>`
But this is also not working.

Thanks for the replies in advance. And if it is not clear what I try to achieve then please post a comment and I will try to elaborate further.

Comment: Using your code, works fine. Video element gets `display: none` at `@media (max-width: 979px) and (min-width: 768px)`. **[Check this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n3tX9/)**

Comment: @kmsdev That is true but because of the autoplay it keeps running the audio of the video

Comment: Yep, It happens because you are only hiding the video element. You can control the width window with javascript, using `window.innerWidth`. I will post an answer with enough help

Comment: Do you need to have autoplay on? Many consider that rude website behavior. Anyway, this might help you turn off autoplay using jQuery: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8143906/set-autoplay-false-on-flowplayer-in-jquery

Comment: @kmsdev Sorry for the late response I was having dinner. I am looking forward to the answer.

Comment: @TylerH Autoplay is necessary because it is the background of the website. The video plays as background and loops. The owner is not yet sure if he wants audio yes or no but in the meantime the video has audio for testing purposes. But the video is about 10mb in size and this is unacceptable as background for mobile users on a dataplan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking to our comments, here is an easy solution. Comments on code will help you to understand it if you need:

**2 working solutions: 1 with jquery | 2 without jquery**

1:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    // domready with jquery
    $(function(){
        // call our function on ready. only if necessary
        WidthControl.Set();

        // handle resize event
        $(window).on('resize', function(){
            WidthControl.Set();
        });

    });

    var WidthControl = {
        current: null,  // variable to get current width when necessary

        Set: function(){  // sets the current width and call DoStuff function
            var w = window.innerWidth;
            this.current = w;
            this.DoStuff();
        },

        DoStuff: function(){  // here we pause (or stop if you want) the video element
            var target = document.getElementById('backgroundvids');
            if( this.current > 0 && this.current < 979 && /*added to prevent onresize calls ->*/ !target.paused ){
                target.autoplay = false;
                target.load();
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

2:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){    // the line that I changed

        // call our function on ready. only if necessary
        WidthControl.Set();

        // handle resize event
         window.onresize = function(){ 
             WidthControl.Set(); 
         }
     };  // removed ')'

    var WidthControl = {
        current: null,  // variable to get current width when necessary

        Set: function(){  // sets the current width and call DoStuff function
            var w = window.innerWidth;
            this.current = w;
            this.DoStuff();
        },

        DoStuff: function(){  // here we pause (or stop if you want) the video element
            var target = document.getElementById('backgroundvids');
            if( this.current > 0 && this.current < 979 && /*added to prevent onresize calls -     >*/ !target.paused ){
                target.autoplay = false;
                target.load();
            }
        }
    };
 </script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I updated your updated fiddle with a movie from w3schools to test. And in here it is working. Only autoplay is not working in jsfiddle. Bye the way here is the link. http://jsfiddle.net/n3tX9/2/

I am going to try on the demosite. I get back to you. Many thanks.

Comment: Looks fine, I edited my answer changing the updated jsfiddle by yours :)

Comment: You can control autoplay reloading the video. Check **[this link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_video_autoplay3)**. Using the code I posted, into `DoStuff()` function change `target.pause()` to `target.autoplay = false; target.load();`. I edited the post to reflect it.

Comment: I have tried the code in the answer but it is not working I begin to think it is maybe a Jquery issue. What about the following could that work? `<div class="ls-mobileview">
<script>
var x = document.getElementById("backgroundvids");
function disableAutoplay()
  { 
  x.autoplay = false;
  x.load();
  } 
</script> 
</div>`

But I believe the code is not executing. How can i execute the function?

Comment: Can't you use the code that I posted in answer? It should work as expected

Comment: Please don't forget I really appreciate all the help that I am getting but I can't get it to work. I will post the entire code in a jsfiddle. This is the code that is inside the Joomla Article and therefore I post the html parts also in the javascript area of jsfiddle because it is one document. The jsfiddle will not work. Thanks again. http://jsfiddle.net/W4s2W/2/
If you want we can go to chat. Maybe that is easier.

Comment: It's ok, don't worry. We are close to make it working. I wait for your jsfiddle to edit my answer with a valid and working solution

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/W4s2W/2/ is the fiddle but it will never work because it is in one field. All text in that field is copied inside a joomla article as html. With no editors so nothing is erased on saving.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54549/discussion-between-kmsdev-and-hennysmafter).